# Finding the prediction interval with polynomial

Tags: r, regression, prediction, logarithm

From the following code, I am trying to find the prediction intervals (95%) when "circulations" are 0.5 and 20:

```
AdvRev = read.csv(url("http://www.stat.tamu.edu/~sheather/book/data_sets.php/AdRevenue.csv"), header=TRUE)
y = AdvRev$AdRevenue
x = AdvRev$Circulation

xsquared=x^2
xcubed=x^3
#I used polynomial regression since it fits better than y~x
m6 = lm(y~x+xsquared+xcubed, data=AdvRev) 

#Bad leverage points were removed from the model.
m9 <- update(m6, subset=(1:70)[-c(2,5,8,20,49,60)])  
summary(m9)
```

Trying to use the following code to find the interval for the final fitted model (m9):

```
predict(m9, newdata=data.frame(x = c(0.5,20)), interval="prediction",level=0.95)
```

However, it is not giving a valid answer. If you may correct my final code, I would really appreciate it.

Comment: This is the result showing up for the last line:

```'newdata' had 2 rows but variables found have 70 rows
 Show Traceback
Error in model.frame.default(Terms, newdata, na.action = na.action, xlev = object$xlevels) : variable lengths differ (found for 'xsquared')```

Comment: Did you look at the contents of `AdvRev`? This examples doesn't seem to be reproducible. In order to predict, all variables in the model must be in the new data.frame. You only have `x`. Not `xsquared` and `xcubed`. So that's why we don't usually do poly terms that way, we use the `poly` function. `lm(y~poly(x,3, raw=TRUE), data=AdvRev) `

Comment: This gave me the answer @MrFlick Thank you so much.